# How can I filter a query by a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to get a list of "Peliculas" filtered by their "Director" in my DirectorDetailView

I can't find the correct syntax to do this. 
Django Version: 2.1.4

```
#MODEL DIRECTOR

class Director(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    fecha_defuncion = models.DateField(
        'Fallecido',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    foto = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/directores/',
        default='images/directores/sin_foto.jpg'
    )

#MODEL PELICULA

class Pelicula(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    url_trailer = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    fecha = models.DateField()
    notas_posibles = (
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5)
    )
    nota = models.IntegerField(
        default=3,
        choices=notas_posibles
    )
    sinopsis = models.TextField(
        max_length=400,
        default="Sin sinopsis"
    )
    caratula = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/peliculas/caratulas',
        default='images/peliculas/caratulas/sin_caratula.jpg'
    )
    imagen_promocional = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/peliculas/imagenes_promocionales',
        default='images/peliculas/imagenes_promocionales/sin_imagen.jpg'
    )
    genero = models.ManyToManyField(
        Genero,
        blank=True,
        related_name='genero'
    )
    director = models.ForeignKey(
        Director,
        on_delete=models.SET('Sin Director')
    )

#MY VIEW

class DirectorDetailView(DetailView):
model = Director
template_name = "videoclub/director.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  
    print(self.model)
    context = super(DirectorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['peliculas'] = Pelicula.objects.all() #HERE
    return context
```

With this code i receive all the "Peliculas" but i only one to get those made by the Director of my view. Dont really know what i'm doing wrong. I dont even know if i have to do this with "DetailView"

Ty guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this in the view at all; you do it in the template.

```
{{ director.nombre }}
{% for pelicula in director.pelicula_set.all %}
  {{ pelicula.titulo }}
  {{ pelicula.sinopsis }} # etc
{% endfor %}
```

You can delete the `get_context_data` method completely.

Comment: Nice! I was looking for that! Thank you so much. I still have so much to learn about django.